# Write an ARM Assembly Language program to compute the nth Fibonacci number

Tags: assembly, arm, fibonacci

I am just starting out in programming and computing and got an assignment thats really confusing me. it has two parts
1.Write an ARM Assembly Language program to compute the nth Fibonacci number. The
nth Fibonacci number is defined recursively as:
Fn= Fn-1 + Fn-2
where F0 = 0 and F1 = 1.
Use R2 for n and compute Fn in R0. Test your program by computing F16 and F32.
2. Using your answer to Q1 as a starting point, write an ARM Assembly Language program
to calculate the largest possible Fibonacci number using (i) 32-bit unsigned arithmetic
and (ii) 32-bit signed arithmetic. Make sure you report the values of n and Fn (in
hexadecimal and decimal) in your project submission.

if (MAX - Fn-1 < Fn-2) // Fn-1 + Fn-2 will be greater than MAX…
break; // therefore Fn-1 is the largest Fibonacci number

So far I have:

```
        AREA    RESET, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY

start   MOV     R1, #16     ; n = 16
        MOV     R3, #0      ; fn1 = 0
        MOV     R0, #1      ; fn = 1
        MOV     R2, #1      ; curr = 1
whn     CMP     R2, R1      ; while (curr < 1)
        BHS     endwhn      ; {
        ADD     R2, R2, #1  ;   curr = curr + 1
        MOV     R4, R0      ;   tmp = fn
        ADD     R0, R0, R3  ;   fn = fn + fn1
        MOV     R3, R4      ;   fn1 = tmp
        B       whn         ; }
endwhn

STOP    B       STOP

        END
```

Comment: Hi Cameron, welcome to SO. You should try to put some effort into formatting your question.

Code snippets should be placed within code blocks. You can use bullets and numbering as well.

Comment: Please dont use random tags - how is this related to Java?

Comment: Also, copy and paste the code into the question.

Comment: You haven't really described your problem here.  You've stated what you want to achieve, and you've provided your current code.  But what exactly does your current code do that it shouldn't do, or not do that it should?  Be as specific as you can.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to test the flags after this instruction.

```
    ADD      R0, R0, R3      ; fn = fn + fn1
```

But it does not set the flags. So add the S suffix.

```
    ADDS     R0, R0, R3      ; fn = fn + fn1
```

Next you want to avoid going around the loop again in the case of on overflow.

(**Edit:** Let's get this right. Branch if it **did not** overflow.)

For 32-bit unsigned, the carry flag (C) is set (CS) on overflow, clear (CC) if the loop should be repeated.

```
    BCC      whn              ; }
```

For 32-bit signed, the overflow flag (V) is set (VS) on overflow, clear (VC) if the loop should be repeated.

```
    BVC      whn              ; }
```

(It's been twenty years since I've done any ARM programming. Assumed AArch32.)